# Sequential data output without writing to disk

Tags: algorithm, sorting

- 4kb memory
- 1gb data
- 8 bytes per data

Sequential data output without writing to disk.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: With ("random access") memory much smaller than data, you *will* need to write and read data many times: If not to a disk, what else is available? Write forward, read forward&backword tape drives?

Comment: @Marat output to stdout from large to small or small to large

Comment: @greybeard It's a interview question.

Comment: Great. In an interview, ask for information until the task/problem/question is clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can only accumulate and output a maximum of 4kb per time through the data.  So you will need at least something like 250,000 passes.

How can you accumulate stuff in a pass?

In pseudocode the idea is like this.

```
while not done:
    for each data (8 bytes) in dataset:
        if this data has never been output:
            if it might belong in the current batch:
                add to current batch (evicting something else if needed)
    if current_batch not empty:
        sort current batch
        emit current batch
        update "never been output" filter
    else:
        done
```

What does that filter look like?  It needs to know three things:

1. What is the maximum value so far emitted?
2. How many times has it been emitted?
3. How many times has it been seen on this pass?

Any value below the maximum value gets ignored.  After you've seen the value enough times, you can add it to the current batch.

Now how about the current batch you're accumulating?  That can be a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) that tells you the maximum value in the batch.  If the heap is not full, or if the current value is below the maximum in the batch, you add it to the batch and lose the current max.

If the heap is arranged in memory so that the smallest is first, when the batch is done you can remove the max, which will free up the last slot (that's how heaps work), and put the max there.  Keep doing that and you'll [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) the batch.  Now you can easily update the filter, and then emit the batch.

I don't think you can get significantly more efficient than this.

If I was asked this in an interview, I'd know the answer, but I'd also see being asked the question as a sign that the company's hiring process is suboptimal.  This would make me less inclined to be hired there unless there was some purpose I could see to why they hired this way.  (I know why FAANGs do.  But at most companies I'd call it a red flag.)

Comment: Where do you store "this data has never been output"?

Comment: @EricJ. It is in the filter, which needs the maximum value ever output (8 bytes), and 2 32-bit counters (8 more bytes).  So that filter takes 16 bytes. You also need 8 bytes for whatever the current value is that you're trying to sort out.  And set aside another 8 bytes for the size of the heap and where you are in it. Add another 8 bytes for working memory and all but 40 bytes is data in the heap.

Comment: The filter is initialized at the start with the minimum representable value, and counters of 0 (never seen, never emitted).

Comment: I guess to "evict somthing else if needed" you would need to sort the current batch as you go? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @EricJ. You simply maintain the heap condition. If you don't need to evict, you add the new element at the end of the heap and "fall down". If you do, you replace the maximum element then "bubble up". But you don't need to be completely sorted - just maintain a heap.